# opennlp does not recognized twiiter input

Tags: twitter, opennlp

I have a file that contain twitter post and I am trying to identify the structure of the twitter post per line, like get the noun ,verb and stuff, using opennlp.

it work perfectly until it reach line that contain hashtag and link only

example :

> #birthday www.mybirthday/test/mypi.com

and give error com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException: no features in text

when I write a sentence next to the line it just work. any idea how to handle it?? there are more then thousand line that almost like the example.

Answer (score 0):

To use the POS tagger, you need to pass tokens, (in laymen terms say individual words). The link contains multiple words separated by a slash `/`. The link in itself is not associated with any Part Of Speech. [See here the list of tags and how they are assigned to a word](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/.). If you want it to identify your link, and give a separate tag to it, say `LN` either give your own training data, [here you will know how to create the training data](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.training.tool)or separate the words in the link as separate token (you can separate a link by slash`/`, question mark`?`, equal to sign `=` or ampersand (`&`)) to get the underlying words and then use the POSTagger to get Part Of Speech (similar case for the hash tag.) For tokenization also, you can use opennlp tokenizer and for your special case, train it. [Go through the documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html), it will help you a lot.